# Vertex is always at origin, despite changing coordinates

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, graphics, glut

I'm trying to work with some OpenGL development on a new Linux installation and no matter what I change the Vertex coordinates to, I end up with a point in the very center of the window (tiny white dot):

[image]

Here's the main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO;

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[1];
```

This is where I can't seem to change the Vertex coordinates:

```
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
```

I pass `GL_FLOAT` into `glVertexAttribPointer` so 0.5f should be 1/2 the screen in both X and Y.

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("Move you little Ass!");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
        return 1;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

and here's the `Vector3f` struct in math_3d.h:

```
struct Vector3f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3f()
    {
    }

    Vector3f(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? No shaders? If that's the case, this answer most likely applies to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097007/how-can-i-make-opengl-draw-something-using-vbos-in-xcode/23100423#23100423.

Comment: To change your vector coordinates you need to call glTranslatef or glRotatef functions. These functions will allow you to move your Object around the frame. Vertices[0] = Vector3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f); will just create a vector with RGB color coding and has nothing to do with the pixel movements. You need to move your Vertices X and Y coordinates around the frame. You might also need to know about glPushMatrix() and glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) functions, if you are drawing shapes on the frame.

Comment: @Reto Koradi  Yea that was it, Thanks!

Comment: @Juniar that family of drawing functions is deprecated, teaching shaders is what people should be doing now rather than the fixed function pipeline